# Explanation of Isotropic Kernel

Tags: machine-learning, regression

What is Isotropic Kernel . What are its features . How can we use it in context of non parametric regression like Kernel Regression ?  An intuitive explanation followed with metrics will be helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2):

An isotropic Kernel is a kernel which depends only on the distance of the kernel arguments,

```
K(x,y) = f(||x-y||)
```

`||.||` is any suitable norm, usually the L2-norm.

Intuitively this means that the direction of the deviation is of no importance. For instance, in two dimensions a change in variable `x1` is equally important to a change in variable `x2` -- which is of course often a too strong assumption. Therefore the predictor variables are often scaled appropriately.

How you can use it in regression? Like any other kernel, but it's often simpler as the number of parameters is often quite small. The isotropic Gaussian for example has only one parameter.

Comment: The property you are referring to is "stationarity" and not "isotropy". An example of isotropic vs anisotropic kernel is the squared exponential (a.k.a. Gaussian or RBF) kernel vs the ARD kernel in this discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370434/ard-kernel-explanation.

Comment: @Chris: sorry, your statement is wrong, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy). "Stationarity", in contrast, is a much broader term.

Comment: While I see your point in the grand scheme of things those terms have very specific meaning in the literature related to kernels and kernel-based methods (see eg http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/genton01a/genton01a.pdf). For example one can use isotropic non-stationary or anisotropic stationary kernels. An example of anisotropic stationary kernel is the ARD kernel that I mentioned above.

Comment: @Chris: sure. In your [reference](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/genton01a/genton01a.pdf), please go on top of page 302. The definition of an isotropic kernel there is quite exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Well... The distinction is crystal clear both in the abstract and conclusions. However, if we want to delve into the specifics of the paper, by reading through section 2 (where the passage you mention belongs) the distinction is again made between "stationary anisotropic" and "stationary isotropic" kernels. Essentially, stationarity and isotropy are different properties.

Comment: @Chris: again, yes, stationarity and isotropy are different properties. Nobody questions that. But in the OP it is specifically asked for isotropy, which in the paper's definition corresponds to "stationary isotropic". For isotropy (or call it stationary isotropy), I gave the sufficiently exact definition. It doesn't matter whether there are other concepts like anisotropy or non-stationarity when it's asked for isotropy.